# CORS error with socket.io (node) and apache running on same server

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cors

I am creating a feature for my website where people can live chat with me. In order to do this, I built the regular part of the site with php and apache, and the chat server with node.js (using socket.io and express). When people go to our site, there is a little bar that slides out from the side if they want to chat with me (in the same window, not a popup). With the chat server running, I see the client trying to connect:

```
info  - socket.io started
Express server listening on port 8000 in development mode
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized 776963641537662118
```

It doesn't go any further, trying to connect via websockets or XHR, and I get the following error on the client side in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://wundertutor.com:8000/socket.io/1/?t=1356208544112. Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true.
```

Also, I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize that it's been a long time since this question was asked, but you might want to try having your node application also allow for CORS. You can do this with the following:

```
io.set('origins', 'http://example.com:80');
```

Where example.com is where the request is coming from. This is what I did on my app and it allowed for CORS requests.

Answer (score 0):

unless you want other domains to be able to access the content being affected by that mod_headers.c, then restrict access control to you domain like this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://wundertutor.com/
</IfModule>
```

i.e. removing the wildcard "*" that the error is complaining about.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your solution and it still isn't working. By the way, I am leaving the node app running if you would like to see the error for yourself.

Comment: I am not seeing the original error any more, but I am seeing a 404 error in the console saying that

`GET http://wundertutor.com/javascripts/socket.io-client/lib/socket.io-client.js 404 (Not Found)`

Looks like your client side may be mis-configured?

socket.io usually wants to serve up the client side javascript on a static route it provides. See the socket.io wiki here [link]https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/How-do-I-serve-the-client

Comment: Sorry about that. I left the node app running but I think it stopped once I logged out of the console. Anyways I ran it using "nohup node app.js &" and it should stay running now. I still can't figure out the original problem though. Nothing I seem to try changes it :/